# Subordinate clause with two verbs

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause, accusative-and-infinitive

> He suggested that tomorrow we find something to do together.

How to say this?

> Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen finden, etwas zusammen zu tun.

or

> Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas zusammen zu tun finden.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using

> "Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas zusammen unternehmen (werden)."

or

> "Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas finden, was wir zusammen machen (können)."

This is not a 1:1 translation, but "unternehmen" can be used here as is does not have to be explicitely planned - e.g. "Lass uns etwas unternehmen" is used like "Let's do something".

If you want to have a 1:1 translation, it would be:

> "Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas finden, was wir zusammen machen."

Personally, i would not say it like that..

Edit: Integrated Alomvar's comment. Thank you Alomvar!

Comment: I think the problem with the 1:1 translation is the missing [subjective mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) (_Konjunktiv_), which makes it sound natural: "_Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas finden, was wir zusammen machen können._" Even though I think subjective statements should not be used: I would say that.

Comment: I think that the first translation lacks the connotation that the "something we do together" must be found first. Your translation states that actually something *will actually be done*. Your second translation may not sound natural, but it contains the intended meaning. In addition, I'd suggest something like *Er schlug vor morgen etwas zu finden, was wir zusammen machen können*, which is also not quite 1:1.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar i get your point and you are right with the first one. But since it is announced as "not 1:1", i would not change it, as it is a more common use i think. please tell me if i disagree. Your last suggestion sounds a bit weird, i can't figure out why at the moment

Comment: Your second translation `Er schlug vor, dass wir morgen etwas finden, was wir zusammen machen.` is as literal as possible *and* conveys the same meaning (without any further context given). So I would call this pretty 1:1.